# How to calculate this integral $\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+x}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Can somebody give mi idea, how to solve this integral?

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+x}\,dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
I&=\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+x}\times\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-x}\,dx\\
&=\int \left(x\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-x^2\right)\,dx
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Expand by $\sqrt{x^2+1}-x$ to remove the root of the denominator. We then have $\int x\sqrt{x^2+1}-x^2 dx $. To solve $\int x\sqrt{x^2+1} dx$, we make the substitution $x^2+1 = u$. The other integral is easy to solve. Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Or without substitution: $$\int x\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx=\frac12\int d(x^2+1)\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac12(x^2+1)^{3/2}+K\;\ldots\ldots+1$$